# App Crashes in UITabBarController delegate method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Hi
I am trying to add and remove tab bar elements dynamically. There are two arrays. One is shown first with an added tabbaritem with name "More" and other array is added to the tabbar when user presses More. User can come back to first array by pressing Less tabbaritem in second array. Problem is that when i frequently press More and Less tabbaritems in sequence More, Less, More, Less, More, Less - The app crashes after last Less. Array seems ok to me and so is tabbar controller. I am not able to figure out the problem.
Below is the code of tab bar delegate method.

```
 - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
 NSLog(@"selected view controller is :%@",viewController);
 if(viewController.view.tag == -1){
     [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:self.level2TabBarItems animated:YES];
     [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
 }else if(viewController.view.tag == -2){
     [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:self.level1TabBarItems animated:YES];
     [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
 }
```

}

Can anyone please let me know where I am doing wrong?
Best Regards

Comment: Can you post the crash logs here?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the crash occurs on line [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:self.level1TabBarItems animated:YES];   Also there is no crash report generated in my Library/Logs folder for this scenario. I have checked with the help of breakpoint that uitabbarcontroller and level1TabbarItems, both are not null or empty.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I guess that you construct new instance of VC in your array, so frequently switching more/less causes calling method from the old instance (is not replaced yet at that moment).

Unfortunatelly `setViewControllers` method (as [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarController/setViewControllers%3aanimated%3a) say) automatically remove old view controllers calling `dealloc` and it seems that there is no other way to reuse them.

In your case you can try to disable selecting tabs until `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` execute implementing (I didn't test it):

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    self.selectLock = YES;
    // your code
    self.selectLock = NO;
}

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    return !self.selectLock;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make comment NSLog here. This is not proper format to print this.

Answer (score 0):

May be your array's are empty. Try to set a breakpoint and you will find the solution which line is causing the crash.

Comment: No sir the arrays are not empty :(

Comment: then debug your app you will definitely find the solution for your crash

Answer (score 0):

I think Both if and else if are not satisfied with this condition

Just Check your Tag with this `NSLog(@"%d",viewController.view.tag);`

Comment: app crashes on [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:self.level1TabBarItems animated:YES]; so i dont think that issue is not in NSLog. Conditions are working fine.